# z-index an absolutely positioned element under a relatively positioned one

Tags: css, z-index, css-position

I am trying to put an absolutely positioned element under a relatively positioned one. The blue box HAS to be relatively positioned due to constraints within the site development.

Imagine a speech bubble is the blue box, the bubble's tail is the :after pseudo-element. I need the green box to go behind both of these as it is to hold a background for these two elements.

```css
div.layer01 {
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
div.layer01:after {  /* This is the tail of the bubble */
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
    content: '\00a0';
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute; 
    right: 20px;
    top: 50px;
    border: 3px #fff solid;
}    

/* This should be behind the tail and the blue box (bubble) */
div.layer01 div.layer02 { 
    background-color: green;
    width: 320px;
    height: 125px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="layer01"> <!-- speech bubble -->
    <div class="layer02">Why isn't this below the blue?</div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus non dolor quis leo malesuada pharetra at in massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
</div>
```

FIX:

Took the element I wanted positioned out of the relatively positioned element then wrapped the contents into a new div. Adds mark up but seems this was the only way.

Comment: You can't place an element *below its container*. Re-think the layout.

Comment: Jared's answer is right. Take his advice and refactor your markup. For more info on z-index: See: http://timkadlec.com/2008/01/detailed-look-at-stacking-in-css/

Comment: Jared's answer is wrong, and hinges entirely on the incorrect claim that the common sense approach is ill defined.  Don't play hacky games when they aren't necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit: I was misinformed, negative indexes were introduced in CSS2.1. This solution is still correct, though my comments about it being a hack are not.**

Child elements, even if absolutely positioned can't be below their parent element unless you use a hack.

The hack is to remove the z-index property from the parent and give the child element a negative z-index

http://jsfiddle.net/uZdy3/1/

```
div.layer01 {
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
}
div.layer01:after {  /* This is the tail of the bubble */
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
    content: '\00a0';
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute; 
    right: 20px;
    top: 50px;
    border: 3px #fff solid;
}    

/* This should be behind the tail and the blue box (bubble) */
div.layer01 div.layer02 { 
    background-color: green;
    width: 320px;
    height: 125px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: -5;
}
```

It would be much better to refactor your layout to avoid this hack, though.

Comment: z-indexes shouldn't have negative values and the behaviour is not guaranteed across browsers.

Comment: I'll have a look at refactoring the code. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: This is not a hack, and behavior is actually guaranteed across browsers.  Host answer is incorrect.  Negative Z-Indices were not legal in CSS2, but they *are* legal in CSS2.1, which came out about a year before this answer was written.  They are supported by all major browsers back through IE4, original Chrome, Firefox 4, original Opera, and original Safari.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: Duly noted about the updated in CSS2.1 however my solution is still correct.

Comment: Many undesirable solutions are strictly legal according to the specification.  However, the justifying case for doing things this way instead of the way the language suggests is a misrepresentation that the direct way is in some fashion a "hack," which isn't actually true.  There was never any point at which CSS2 said this was a bad idea.  Whereas your implementation strategy is legal, the answer you gave uses false data to support its approach, leading to a radically undesirable overcomplicated strategy that needs explanation (what most would call "a hack.")

Answer (score 3):

The correct response, which has been safe and legal since CSS2.1 in mid-2011, is to use a negative Z-Index.  This behavior is well supported in all major browsers, going back to original Chrome, original Safari, original Opera, IE4, and Firefox 3.  The last browser to support this began in 2008.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index